# Auto-install packages from inside makefile

Tags: makefile, package

Goal: when the user types 'make packages', automatically search for the package libx11-dev (required for my program to compile) and, if not found, install it.  Here's a stripped-down version of my makefile:

```
PACKAGES = $(shell if [ -z $(dpkg -l | grep libx11-dev) ]; then sudo apt-get install libx11-dev; fi)

[other definitions and targets]

packages: $(PACKAGES)
```

When I type 'make packages', I'm prompted for the super-user password.  If entered correctly, it then hangs indefinitely.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible from within the makefile?  If so, how?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the `shell` function acts like backticks in the shell: it takes the output to stdout and returns it as the value of the function.  So, apt-get is not hanging, it's waiting for you to enter a response to some question.  But you cannot see the question because make has taken the output.

The way you're doing this is not going to work.  Why are you using `shell` instead of just writing it as a rule?

```
packages:
        [ -z `dpkg -l | grep libx11-dev` ] && sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
.PHONY: packages
```

Comment: I see a template here; pull out libx11-dev and have it work on a list of packages?

Comment: @MadScientist
Thanks very much!  This works, except that if the package is already installed, I get the error: 
       "/bin/sh: 1: [: ii: unexpected operator"
which is presumably related to the fact that the output of the command dpkg -l | grep libx11-dev is
       "ii  libx11-dev          2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2"

Comment: Add quotes: `[ -z "\`dpkg -l | grep libx11-dev\`" ]`

Answer (score 4):

I figured out a better way, which avoids the problem of having unexpected arguments to the if statement:

```
if ! dpkg -l | grep libx11-dev -c >>/dev/null; then sudo apt-get install libx11-dev; fi
```

The -c flag on grep makes it return the number of lines in dpkg -l which contain the string libx11-dev, which will either be 0 (if uninstalled) or 1 (if installed), allowing

```
dpkg -l | grep libx11-dev -c
```

to be treated like an ordinary boolean variable.